# Array equal another array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a loop that goes something like this, where arrayfunction sets all array values and compute_with_both_arrays computes a number based on both these arrays.

They way i did it below does not work for array1 = array2. Is there a way i can do this without running the arrayfuncion twice in each loop?

```
float sum = 0;

float array1[10];
arrayfunction(0, array1);

for(i=1; i<10; i++) {
  float array2[10]
  arrayfunction(1, array2);

  float s;
  s = compute_with_both_arrays(array1, array2);
  sum = sum + s;

  array1 = array2;
}
```

Comment: `array1` is not assignable. If your snippet compiled I suggest you get rid of your compiler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to manually copy the memory from one array to another using a function like [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/).

So for instance:

```
memcpy(array1, array2, sizeof(array1));
```

Keep in mind that we can use the `sizeof` operator on `array1` because it's an explicit array allocated on the stack.  As a commenter noted, we pass the size of the destination to avoid a buffer over-run.  Note that the same technique could be done for a statically allocated array as well, but you *cannot* use it on an array dynamically allocated on the heap using `malloc`, or with some pointer-to-an-array ... in those situations, you must explicitly pass the size of the array in bytes as the third argument.

Finally, you'll want to use `memcpy` over a `for`-loop because the function is typically optimized for copying blocks of memory using instructions at the machine-code level that will far out-strip the efficiency of a for-loop, even with compiler optimizations turned on.

Comment: It's worth noting that modern compilers will automatically turn a for-loop copy into a call to `memcpy` (or an unrolled copy sequence, if the size is small) on their own.  That said, yes, it's better to call `memcpy`.

Comment: For safety you should always pass the size of the destination array: `sizeof array1` and not `sizeof array2`.